# SpriteKit collisions issue between two objects controlled by screen touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I cant get the spaceship and the enemy2 to collide,  It does not give any indication visually or in debug area that it has collided. 
Both of these are controlled by screen touches and the others are not.

The spaceship will collide with the enemy and goldcoin.  The enemy2 will collide with enemy.
  I flagged the two sections at the bottom that I think are causing the issue.

New to coding so a solid explanations with visual help would be appreciated.

```
override func didEvaluateActions() {
    checkCollisions()
}



func spaceshipHit(goldCoin: SKSpriteNode) {
   // added for score jan 13
    goldcoinCount += 1
    goldCoin.removeFromParent()
}

func spaceshipHit2(enemy: SKSpriteNode) {
    enemy.removeFromParent()
}



func spaceshipHit(enemy: SKSpriteNode) {
    invincible = true
    // added for score attempt jan 13
    lives -= 1
    print(lives)
    enemy.removeFromParent()
    let blinkTimes = 10.0
    let duration = 3.0
    let blinkAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: duration) { node, elapsedTime in
        let slice = duration / blinkTimes
        let remainder = Double(elapsedTime).truncatingRemainder(
            dividingBy: slice)
        node.isHidden = remainder > slice / 2
    }
    let setHidden = SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
        self?.spaceship.isHidden = false
        self?.invincible = false
    }
    spaceship.run(SKAction.sequence([blinkAction, setHidden]))

}
```

This is the block of code that I think is not being activated.

```
func spaceshipHit(enemy2: SKSpriteNode) {
    invincible = true
    lives -= 1
    print(lives)

    let blinkTimes = 10.0
    let duration = 3.0
    let blinkAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: duration) { node, elapsedTime in
        let slice = duration / blinkTimes
        let remainder = Double(elapsedTime).truncatingRemainder(
            dividingBy: slice)
        node.isHidden = remainder > slice / 2
    }
    let setHidden = SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
        self?.spaceship.isHidden = false
        self?.invincible = false
    }
    spaceship.run(SKAction.sequence([blinkAction, setHidden]))

}


func checkCollisions() {

    var hitGoldCoins: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "goldCoin") { node, _ in
        let goldCoin = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if goldCoin.frame.intersects(self.spaceship.frame) {
            hitGoldCoins.append(goldCoin)
        }
    }

    for goldCoin in hitGoldCoins {
        spaceshipHit(goldCoin: goldCoin)
    }

    if invincible {
        return
    }

    var hitEnemiesToEnemies: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "enemy") { node, _ in
        let enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if node.frame.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20).intersects(
        self.enemy2.frame) {
        hitEnemiesToEnemies.append(enemy)
        }
    }

    for enemy in hitEnemiesToEnemies {
        spaceshipHit2(enemy:enemy)
    }


    var hitEnemies: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "enemy") { node, _ in
        let enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if node.frame.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20).intersects(
            self.spaceship.frame) {
            hitEnemies.append(enemy)

        }
    }

    for enemy in hitEnemies {
        spaceshipHit(enemy: enemy)
    }

    if invincible {
        return
    }
```

This is another suspect section.

```
    var hitEnemies2: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "enemy2") { node, _ in
        let enemy2 = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if enemy2.frame.intersects(
            self.spaceship.frame) {
            hitEnemies2.append(enemy2)
        }
    }


    // this is the section that trys to get the ship to hit shadow enemy
    /*var hitEnemies2: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "enemy2") { node, _ in
        let enemy2 = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if node.frame.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20).intersects(
            self.spaceship.frame) {
            hitEnemies2.append(enemy2)
        }
    }
    */


    for enemy2 in hitEnemies2 {
        spaceshipHit(enemy2: enemy2)
    }


}
```

Comment: Nobody is going to inspect so many lines of code.  Make it concise.

Comment: Thx,  I deleted most of the code down to where I think the problem is.  If question is still bad let me know and I will delete the whole thing and try and ask a different way.

Comment: When I run a search for 'mask,' I get no hits, suggesting that you haven't set category bit maks.

Comment: @ElTomato he is not using `SKPhysics` he made his own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I am seeing, you never assign "enemy2" to the name of your enemy, so `enumerateChildNodes(withName: "enemy2") { node, _ in
        let enemy2 = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if enemy2.frame.intersects(
            self.spaceship.frame) {
            hitEnemies2.append(enemy2)
        }
    }`

should be empty, meaning no node is hit.